# SQL Server Permissions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This is a typical SQL Server error, I know:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
'GetStaffDirectoryListingsByCompany', database 'MyDB', schema 'dbo'.
```

I was able to fix it in SSMS by adding the EXECUTE permission for the 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. I tried to add specific AppPool for this application 'IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool' but could not locate it in SSMS. Why is this happening?

My question is simple: for a DB with dozens of stored procedures, how do I add this permission once instead of having to manually do it for each stored procedure?

I couldn't get the following to work:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx

**UPDATE**

I should point out some background to this problem:

First, my Win7 dev machine was upgraded to Windows 10 and somehow all the projects were associated with the DefaultAppPool in IIS (as well as their own App Pools).

Second, the DB was restored from a version on a production server to my local dev machine (maybe why permissions were messed up?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either grant `EXECUTE` permission on the schema or on the whole DB, for example:

```
USE [myDatabase]
go

-- Grant EXECUTE permission on the schema dbo
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [myUser]
go
```

or

```
USE [myDatabase]
go

-- Grant EXECUTE permission on the DB
GRANT EXECUTE TO [myUser]
go
```

I hope this helps.

---

Following up to the comment by IrishChieftain:

Upon reading your particular scenario more carefully, I see that it seems like SSMS is not showing you `IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool` on `myDB` database.

Most likely the root cause is that a different group is granting the application access to the DB. I am not an IIS expert, and I am not sure why granting access to the default pool worked (The SIDs should not have matched, could it be that your app is actually running under the default application pool?).

In any case, I would recommend trying the following: Replace `myUser` with the more specific pool `IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool`; the command should create the user implicitly, and it should also start showing up in SSMS.

Please let us know if it worked, we can try a different approach.

Comment: I am developing locally using Integrated Security in connection string. In this scenario, what is "myUser"?

Comment: In IIS DefaultAppPool had 11 applications using it!! I right-clicked the DefaultAppPool and selected "View Applications". I changed the AppPool for MyApp to MyAppPool. Don't know why this is happening in IIS. 

MyAppPool shows two applications using it. I removed the one that was prefixed with "/". I removed the site from IIS but MyAppPool is still showing one site using it and won't let me delete the app pool.

Comment: I fixed the double entry in IIS. Still getting a permissions error for a table: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Staff', database 'MyDB', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: Try granting `SELECT` permission to `IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool` the same way: `GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[Staff] TO [IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPool]`; or if you prefer, you can grant the permission on the schema.

Comment: Tried it, same error. And I wasn't able to run "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" on Windows 10.

Comment: Hi Raul, I got around it by granting Execute on 'public' role for each stored procedure. Is this advisable and is there an easier way to do this just once for all stored procedures?

Comment: It is not advisable to grant execute permission on `public`, which mean grant permission to everyone. I would recommend using SQL Profiler to find out the name of login IIS is actually using, and grant permission only to that principal. In order to grant execute on all SPs, try `GRANT EXECUTE TO [MyUser]`, replacing `[MyUser]` with the appropriate user name.